# Google spreadsheets: increase specific number in formula when dragging

Tags: excel, formula, spreadsheet

For my work I need to create a spreadsheet with multiple formulas.

For now everything is going great but I have the following problem.

I have column A, with the following formula:

```
=ALS(Anchors!$P$5 = 1; "x"; "")
```

Cells A2:A6 all need this formula, but the next 5 cells, so A7:12 need

```
=ALS(Anchors!$P$5 = 2; "x"; "")
```

And so every 5 cells the = 1 increments by 1.

I have tried selecting 10 cells, with the 2 formulas and grabbing them down, but this didnt work.

PS. =ALS is the dutch term for =IF

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it directly by pulling down, but you could do a calculation based on the row like (the Dutch equivalent of) this:-

```
=IF(Anchors!$P$5=INT((ROWS(A$1:A1)+4)/5),"x","")
```